# jQuery .on and .trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jquery

i´ve got an html element:

```
...
<div class="preferences">
    ...
    <button class="menuButton cpnScanPressed" id="btnScanCpn">Scan</button>
    ...
</div>
...
```

and an event bind on it:

```
$('.preferences').on('click', '#btnScanCpn', handleScanCpn);
```

now i want to trigger that event if ESC is pressed:

```
/* discard changes if pressing esc */
input.keydown(function(e) {
if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("DEBUG"); // console says:"DEBUG"
    console.log($(".cpnScanPressed#btnScanDps")); // console says:"jQuery( )"
    $("#btnScanDps").trigger('click'); // wont fire!
    }
});
```

so what seems to be the trouble ?! it seems the selector is not working ?! i dont understand it..

Comment: `#btnScanDps` or `#btnScanCpn`? (haha somebody favorited this question)

Comment: spell mistake? `btnScanDps` & `btnScanCpn` ?

Comment: I don't see any element matching `#btnScanDps` in your markup.  The selector is working, it's just not finding anything.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a typo.

Comment: wooooar ;) but .. ok .. i dont think i have seen this on my own - today ;) thank you :P ^^

Comment: @Jacedc What's so amusing about somebody favouriting this question? I regularly favourite low quality questions so I know to come back and check them again (that usually means cast delete votes once they've been closed, but occasionally reverting downvotes and voting to re-open if they've been improved).

Comment: Ah yes, I guess for moderating purposes it makes sense. Didn't think of it like that...

Comment: @Jacedc That's the exact same way I came here two days later, to see how it turned ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `id`s `#btnScanDps` and `#btnScanCpn` that don't correspond with eachother. I'm guessing it was a typo?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use

```
$("#btnScanCpn").click();
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your IDs. You are binding an event to `#btnScanDps`, which does not exist. Use the correct one: `#btnScanCpn`.

```
console.log($(".cpnScanPressed#btnScanCpn"));
    $("#btnScanCpn").trigger('click'); 
}
```